# ros1_bridge build error for Turtlebot3

Tags: ros2, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to build  `ros1_bridge` from source and facing the following issue. Any idea where I am going wrong? It seems to be pointing to Turtlebot3's sound message/service:

```
$ colcon build --packages-select ros1_bridge --cmake-force-configure --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=FALSE
Starting >>> ros1_bridge
[Processing: ros1_bridge]                            
[Processing: ros1_bridge]                                    
--- stderr: ros1_bridge                                      
CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/generated/turtlebot3_msgs__srv__Sound__factories.cpp.o: In function `ros1_bridge::Factory<turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > >::convert_1_to_2(turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > const&, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >&)':
turtlebot3_msgs__srv__Sound__factories.cpp:(.text+0x284): multiple definition of `ros1_bridge::Factory<turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > >::convert_1_to_2(turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > const&, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >&)'
CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/generated/turtlebot3_msgs__msg__Sound__factories.cpp.o:turtlebot3_msgs__msg__Sound__factories.cpp:(.text+0x284): first defined here
CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/generated/turtlebot3_msgs__srv__Sound__factories.cpp.o: In function `ros1_bridge::Factory<turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > >::convert_2_to_1(turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > const&, turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >&)':
turtlebot3_msgs__srv__Sound__factories.cpp:(.text+0x2a0): multiple definition of `ros1_bridge::Factory<turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > >::convert_2_to_1(turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > const&, turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >&)'
CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/generated/turtlebot3_msgs__msg__Sound__factories.cpp.o:turtlebot3_msgs__msg__Sound__factories.cpp:(.text+0x2a0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libros1_bridge.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< ros1_bridge    [ Exited with code 2 ]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1min 3s]
  1 package failed: ros1_bridge
  1 package had stderr output: ros1_bridge
```

These are my steps:

**Terminal 1:**

Source ROS 1 workspace:

```
$ source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

**Terminal 2:**

Source ROS 2 workspace:

```
$ source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash
$ source ~/ros2_dd_ws/install/setup.bash
```

**Terminal 3:**

ros1_bridge workspace get source:

```
$ cd ~/ros1_bridge_ws/src
$ git clone -b dashing https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge.git
$ . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
$ . ~/colcon_ws/install/setup.bash
ROS_DISTRO was set to 'melodic' before. Please make sure that the environment does not mix paths from different distributions.
```

Verify environment:

```
$ echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH | tr ':' '\n'
/home/swaroophs/ros2_dd_ws/install/rosrect-listener-agent
/home/swaroophs/catkin_ws/devel
/opt/ros/melodic
```

ros1_bridge build (FAILS):

```
$ colcon build --packages-select ros1_bridge --cmake-force-configure --cmake-args -DBUILD_TESTING=FALSE
Starting >>> ros1_bridge
[Processing: ros1_bridge]                            
[Processing: ros1_bridge]                                    
--- stderr: ros1_bridge                                      
CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/generated/turtlebot3_msgs__srv__Sound__factories.cpp.o: In function `ros1_bridge::Factory<turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > >::convert_1_to_2(turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > const&, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >&)':
turtlebot3_msgs__srv__Sound__factories.cpp:(.text+0x284): multiple definition of `ros1_bridge::Factory<turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > >::convert_1_to_2(turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > const&, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >&)'
CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/generated/turtlebot3_msgs__msg__Sound__factories.cpp.o:turtlebot3_msgs__msg__Sound__factories.cpp:(.text+0x284): first defined here
CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/generated/turtlebot3_msgs__srv__Sound__factories.cpp.o: In function `ros1_bridge::Factory<turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > >::convert_2_to_1(turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > const&, turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >&)':
turtlebot3_msgs__srv__Sound__factories.cpp:(.text+0x2a0): multiple definition of `ros1_bridge::Factory<turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >, turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > >::convert_2_to_1(turtlebot3_msgs::msg::Sound_<std::allocator<void> > const&, turtlebot3_msgs::Sound_<std::allocator<void> >&)'
CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/generated/turtlebot3_msgs__msg__Sound__factories.cpp.o:turtlebot3_msgs__msg__Sound__factories.cpp:(.text+0x2a0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libros1_bridge.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< ros1_bridge    [ Exited with code 2 ]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1min 3s]
  1 package failed: ros1_bridge
  1 package had stderr output: ros1_bridge
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354302/ros1_bridge-build-error-for-turtlebot3/) by [swaroophs](https://answers.ros.org/users/53852/swaroophs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems to be a bug in the `ros1_bridge` due to the fact that in the `turtlebot3_msgs` package there is a message and service with the same name: `Sound`. That case wasn't handled correctly.

Please see https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/pull/272 which fixes the problem on master. Backports of the various ROS distros will need to happen too.

You should be able to apply the patch locally to the `dashing` branch you are using before building the `ros1_bridge` package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [swaroophs](https://answers.ros.org/users/53852/swaroophs/) on 2020-06-08**:
Thanks @Dirk for commenting on this so quickly! I tried out the patch in `__init__.py` locally and it works!

P.S: Thanks for being so active on these forums. I pretty much see you everywhere some one has a ROS 2 related question helping them. I really appreciate the time and effort you put in :). Big fan.